# Url rewrite mod_rewrite questions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

In my application I want to implement URL rewriting to make the links SEO friendly

```
1.http://example.com/item.php?act=view&id=192
2.http://example.com/feedback.php?id=146
```

TO

```
1.http://example.com/items/itemsname
2.http://www.example.com/username
```

Questions

1)I am bit confused though, do I need to change all the links in my code to http://example.com/items/itemsname and use rewriting to translate it to http://example.com/item.php?act=view&id=192?

or

I can leave my code as it is http://example.com/item.php?act=view&id=192 and just rewrite it to translate to http://example.com/items/itemsname (option 2 looks more realistic as otherwise without the .htaccess nothing will work)

2)How can this be done in Apache and Php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few ways to accomplish this, I would say that the easiest way with your current PHP would be to change your links to something like this:

```
http://example.com/items/id-itemsname
http://example.com/id-username
```

So a real example would look like this:

```
http://example.com/items/192-Wash-Machine
http://example.com/feedback/146-Jon-Lin
```

And then you can easily use this rules to convert it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^items/([0-9]+)-.*$ /item.php?act=view&id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^feedback/([0-9]+)-.*$ /feedback.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This way you can completely ignore the title and grab just the ID out of it and use your current script while still displaying the title to the users.

Another way would be like you mentioned and it would look like this:

```
http://example.com/items/itemsname
http://example.com/feedback/username
```

You would then need to change you PHP to find the feedback and items by name, so they would look like this:

```
http://example.com/item.php?act=view&name=Wash Machine
http://example.com/feedback.php?username=Jon Lin
```

And the rule would be something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^items/([^/]+)/?$ /item.php?act=view&name=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^feedback/([^/]+)/?$ /feedback.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: RewriteCond need to be RewriteRule at the end of each condition I think, Thanks very much for the detailed answer!

Comment: @Athanatos that's my bad it was a typo thanks for spotting that ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I am bit confused though, do I need to change all the links in my code to http://example.com/items/itemsname and use rewriting to translate it to http://example.com/item.php?act=view&id=192?

You want to do this if you can. This means you don't have another layer of processing for *every link that gets clicked*.

The translating is a little ambiguous. For example:

`/username` -> `/feedback.php?id=146`

The "username" I assume is something like "sam", but the "id" is a number. The rewrite module knows **nothing** about this mapping, nothing in the htaccess file knows anything about how usernames maps to ids or how item names map to ids. The only thing that can be done is using a `RewriteMap` that is defined in the server/vhost config that accesses this mapping.

What you are better off doing is using php. Map the item and usernames to the `item.php` and `feedback.php` scripts. Have those scripts figure out the id's based on the names. **And** have those scripts check the request URI to see if the request was for the php files directly instead of the SEO looking URLs and have them redirect as needed.

The only thing you want mod_rewrite to do is do the forward mapping:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ^item/(.*)$ /item.php?act=view&name=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ^(.*)$ /feedback.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Here, you'd look for the "`name`" parameter, map those to the ID's that you need, then proceed normally.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you: [URL Rewrites and 301 Redirects - How Does It All Work?](http://moz.com/blog/url-rewrites-and-301-redirects-how-does-it-all-work)

Personally, I think the correct way is changing all the links and using an .htaccess file to rewrite the urls (obviously you will need to convert the nice-name [a.k.a slug] into an id after the rewrite). I try to avoid redirections unless they are 100% necessary, and this is not the case. Something like this:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^items/([0-9a-zA-Z\-\_].*)$ item.php?act=view&slug=$1 [L]
```

Regarding the links, you can change the they manually (I recommend that) or via JavaScript, making some kind of translate function after the user click.